# SVG To Multipage PDF

Tags: java, svg, apache-fop, docbook, batik

I am trying to convert **SVG to a multi page PDF document**. I was using **Apache Batik** for the conversion, but there is no provision for **multi page** pdfs in it. After doing some research I got to know about **docbook** and it worked quite well. It uses **ANT scripts** for the conversion.

I wanted to know how the **docbook** is dealing with the multi page PDFs because docbook uses Apache FOP which uses Apache Batik for SVG to PDF conversion.

Does it create single PDF files and eventually combines them to make a single PDF?
And if it is doing the same as above, then I myself will create single PDFs using Apache Batik and combine them using PDFBox.

Thanks.

**Solution Using XSL-FO with SVG as external graphic or as embedded SVG**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master page-height="2339px" page-width="1654px" master-name="PageMaster">
        <fo:region-body margin="0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:external-graphic src="url(new sample.svg)" width="100%" height="100%" content-width="100%" content-height="100%"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:external-graphic src="url(new sample2.svg)" width="100%" height="100%" content-width="100%" content-height="100%"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: We too are using Batik library to create pdf document from svg file. Single page export is limitation of this library used to export PDFs and currently page size is simply increased to accommodate more data. Basically my text is too long and I want it to be displayed in multiple pages in a PDF document. Since you have achieved this using docbook, can you please guide us how to implement this in our application. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. FOP is using the XSL FO standard. You define things like the page geometry, rules for keeping content together and flow content blocks into it. It is not creating each page as PDF and joining them. It only uses Batik to convert the SVG to PDF objects for inclusion in the PDF output. So Batik is only creating a "block" area ... like an image although in vector format ... and it is but one of the blocks used to flow into the page geometry.

Comment: alright, so i am finally creating XSL-FO with external graphic as SVG and converting them to PDF. Please find the sample XSL-FO in the Question edit. Additionally thanks for the help.